# Function to truncate table on weekdays

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to write a function to truncate a particular table if a day of week is between Tuesday to Saturday. I tried the below code, but `if` condition is not working. Can someone please help me out.

```
create or replace FUNCTION   TRUNCATE_TABLE    RETURN NUMBER
IS
  --DECLARE VARIABLES
  l_day_of_week    VARCHAR2(15);
  l_table_name CONSTANT VARCHAR2(40) := 'ABC';

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select (to_char(sysdate,''DaY'')) from dual ' 
     INTO l_day_of_week ;

  IF l_day_of_week in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
                       'Thursday','Friday','Saturday') 
  THEN  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ABC' ;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_day_of_week);
  END IF;

  RETURN 0;

END;
```

Comment: Just add `TRIM(l_day_of_week)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF TRIM(l_day_of_week) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
                       'Thursday','Friday','Saturday')
```

The default return type is like `CHAR(9)`..
 9 being *Maximum* length of a day of week (Thursday)

So `Monday` would be appended with spaces!! Unless you use `FMDAY`

So, `TRIM()` would remove all the padded trailing spaces!

You can try out the demo below with the use of 'FM' ([Format Mask](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/gl/fmtmsk.htm))

**With out FM**

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate+level,'Day'),length(to_char(sysdate+level,'Day')) as length from dual
  2  connect by level <= 7;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+LEVEL,'DAY')             LENGTH
------------------------------------ ----------
Tuesday                                       9
Wednesday                                     9
Thursday                                      9
Friday                                        9
Saturday                                      9
Sunday                                        9
Monday                                        9

7 rows selected.
```

**With FM**

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate+level,'FMDAY'),length(to_char(sysdate+level,'FMDaY')) as length from dual
  2  connect by level <= 7;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+LEVEL,'FMDAY')           LENGTH
------------------------------------ ----------
TUESDAY                                       7
WEDNESDAY                                     9
THURSDAY                                      8
FRIDAY                                        6
SATURDAY                                      8
SUNDAY                                        6
MONDAY                                        6

7 rows selected.
```

Finally,

`l_day_of_week = to_char(sysdate,'DaY')`

Would Do, You save a Dynamic SQL call!

Comment: Oh my god.. Thanks a lot. Never knew it could be a trim issue..My queries are like me--never do anything for trimming :) But thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to truncate this table once per day, I'd use a DBMS_SCHEDULER job and put the date logic inside the job:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TRUNCATE_TABLE    
IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ABC' ;
END;

begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'JOB_TRUNCATE_TABLE'
     ,job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
     ,job_action => 'begin truncate_table; end; '

     ,start_date      => to_timestamp_tz('2014-02-24 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin',
                                         'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr')
     ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=22;BYDAY=Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri'
     ,enabled => TRUE
     ,comments => 'Truncate table job, runs Monday to Friday at 22:00');
end;
```

Comment: No actually. I would call this function from informatica presession. So not a schedule job